# deadlock with repeatable read isolation level

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, deadlock

Trying to understand deadlock that is occurring with repeatable read isolation level when the stored proc is invoked.

This is the deadlock xml :

```
    <TextData>
  <deadlock-list>
 <deadlock victim="process6fac029848">
  <process-list>
   <process id="process6fac029848" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="KEY: 8:72078600230076416 (d3c590b351cd)" waittime="1171" 
            ownerId="26116633497" transactionname="delete" lasttranstarted="2021-01-07T10:35:38.317" XDES="0x12553cbe3b0" 
            lockMode="U" schedulerid="3" kpid="19776" status="suspended" spid="92" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" 
            lastbatchstarted="2021-01-07T10:35:38.310" lastbatchcompleted="2021-01-07T10:35:38.310" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.310" 
            clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="web01" hostpid="34852" loginname="someuser" 
            isolationlevel="repeatable read (3)" xactid="26116633497" currentdb="8" currentdbname="db1" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673316896" 
            clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="db1.schema.deleteSP" line="124" stmtstart="8308" stmtend="8870" 
            sqlhandle="somehandle">
UPDATE [schema].[TableName] WITH(UPDLOCK)
        SET
            Status = 1 /* STATUS_DELETED */,
            userid = @id,
            UpdateTime = GETUTCDATE()
        FROM @oldatt oa
        WHERE [TableName].[Id] = oa.Id     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 8 Object Id = 1688915952]    </inputbuf>
   </process>
   <process id="process6fab017088" taskpriority="0" logused="284" waitresource="KEY: 8:72064801531101184 (4b819525e255)" waittime="1283" 
   ownerId="26116632474" transactionname="delete" lasttranstarted="2021-01-07T10:35:38.290" XDES="0x44037ec3b0" 
   lockMode="X" schedulerid="25" kpid="25152" status="suspended" spid="53" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" 
   lastbatchstarted="2021-01-07T10:35:38.287" lastbatchcompleted="2021-01-07T10:35:38.283" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.283" 
   clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="web02" hostpid="57552" loginname="someuser" 
   isolationlevel="repeatable read (3)" xactid="26116632474" currentdb="8" currentdbname="db1" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673316896" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="db1.schema.deleteSP" line="124" stmtstart="8308" stmtend="8870" sqlhandle="somehandle">
UPDATE [schema].[TableName] WITH(UPDLOCK)
        SET
            Status = 1 /* STATUS_DELETED */,
            userid = @id,
            UpdateTime = GETUTCDATE()
        FROM @oldatt oa
        WHERE [TableName].[Id] = oa.Id     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 8 Object Id = 1688915952]    </inputbuf>
   </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
   <keylock hobtid="72078600230076416" dbid="8" objectname="db1.schema.TableName" indexname="IX_TableName_Id_Status_userid_UpdateTime" id="lock287c93a100" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72078600230076416">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process6fab017088" mode="U" />
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process6fac029848" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
   <keylock hobtid="72064801531101184" dbid="8" objectname="db1.schema.TableName" indexname="IX_TableName_SomeId_Id" id="lock55fc471880" mode="S" associatedObjectId="72064801531101184">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process6fac029848" mode="S" />
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process6fab017088" mode="X" requestType="convert" />
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
  </resource-list>
 </deadlock>
</deadlock-list>
</TextData>
```

the create table with relevant indices :

```
CREATE TABLE [schema].[TableName](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    [SomeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Userid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UpdateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [RecordStatus] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
--- 2 indexes that are part of deadlock 
IX_TableName_SomeId_Id = filtered Index - SomeId, Id (include status) where status = 0
IX_TableName_Id_Status_userid_UpdateTime - non clustered index - Id include(status, userid, updatetime)
```

The SP call is :

- isolation level repeatable read
- starts transaction
- does a select from the base table and inserts the rows that will be affected into a temp variable.
- executes another SP
- updates the base table. <<--- this is where the deadlock happens
- merges the data with some business logic
- if no error, commits transaction

The base table has trigger that does insert and updates to audit table for tracking changes.

I am just trying to wrap my head around why I am getting too many deadlocks.

**Update :**

```
declare @oldtable(
        Id bigint,
        someId int
        PRIMARY key clustered (id)
    )
    insert into @oldtable (
        id,
        someid
    )
    select id, someid
    from [schema].[TableName]
    where id = @id and status = 0 and someid = @someid
```

Stored procedure flow control :

```
variables 
    @id 
    @someid 
    
begin 
    set nocount on
    set transaction isolation level repeatable read
    set xact_abort on

    begin tran delete
    begin try

    declare @oldtable(
        Id bigint,
        someId int
        PRIMARY key clustered (id)
    )
    insert into @oldtable (
        id,
        someid
    )
    select id, someid
    from [schema].[TableName]
    where id = @id and status = 0 and someid = @someid 

    some SP runs

    -- update statememt that causes deadlock 
    -- it basically sets status = 1 -- deleted (soft delete)

    -- merge data into tables using CTE and MERGE 
    END TRY

    begin catch 
        -- error handling 
        -- roll back tran 
    end catch

    if @@trancount > 0
    begin
        commit tran delete
    END

END
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's my hypothesis:

Let's call the deadlocking calls of the proc *P1* and *P2*.

Both *P1* and *P2* use the filtered index to locate rows. Because this is Repeatable Read without other hints, they use S locks, and do not release them.
They happen to include a common row. We'll call its location in the filtered index *Row A*.

At this point both P1 and P2 have S locks on *Row A*.

Now, the updates begin.

*P1* reads from the other index to locate rows that need to be updated. It uses U locks as it reads, and places a U lock on *Row B*, which actually represents the same row as A, just in a different index.

Now *P1* has an S lock on *Row A*, and a U lock on *Row B*.

*P1* sees that it has a row to modify, and begins the process. It must also delete the row from the filtered index, which will require an X lock.

*P1* tries to convert its S lock to an X lock, but is blocked by *P2*'s S lock.

*P2* begins its update. It tries to acquire a U lock on *Row B*, but is blocked by *P1*'s U lock. **Deadlock**.

I believe that using the UPDLOCK hint on the initial select should allow you to avoid the deadlock.

Comment: +1 on UPDLOCK.  To avoid deadlocks, acquire your restrictive locks earlier.  And note that REPEATABLE READ is doing what you requested and preventing a lost update.  It generates a deadlock to prevent the second transaction fro committing.

Comment: I implemented the fix (added with UPDLOCK in select) , but it is still deadlocking on the `UPDATE [schema].[TableName] WITH(UPDLOCK)`

Comment: @Forrest https://gist.github.com/TheRockStarDBA/5a17990de44e4f42ae1f032e5c4f8f62

Comment: Yeh .. thats what I see as well. which is weird. Plus started getting deadlock on the select as well.

Comment: @Forrest interesting .. I will update on Thursday to see if we are still getting deadlocks.

Comment: @Forrest seems to be working - atleast I am not getting the deadlock on the same select. Reduced deadlocks from 5K per day to 2 digit numbers ! Will investigate more. thanks a lot for your help !